# indian calendar needed

Tags: windows

I want a 100 years calendar which shows certain Indian special days like Amavasya and Poornima.

I want to find the day for Poornima or Amavasya  for example - in the year 1936. When was Shivratri aur janmasthami. I want to find day according to these specifications.

If there is a program that can do this, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amavasya and poornima (New Moon and Full Moon) are calculated based on a complex formula   defined in below [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_moon). You can try developing a small program out of that. :-)

Comment: that would place the question outside of the scope of this site then.